# Is there a tool or browser add-on which will overlay images with their filename?

Tags: images, tools

Is there a tool or browser add-on which will overlay images with their filename and/or alt tag? Without needing to mouse over each one.

Something like this made up example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Web Developer toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) has items under its Images menu to display the image alt, dimensions, path(which will include the filename, but there's not an option for *just* the filename), filesize, and a lot of other stuff. There's also an item(View Image Information) that will pop open a new tab with just the images from the current layout, and a bunch of basic information about them.

The items to display properties don't overlay exactly as you describe. They tend to push the images around a little because they're placed into the page, but otherwise the toolbar does everything you want and a *lot* more. If you're not feeling terribly picky about the overlay, I'd just go with it.